# What is the difference between Cloud ML Engine and Compute Engine in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have used Compute Engine previously and want to train some predictive models. I was wondering which Engine to use? I am new to Cloud ML engine. Is there an advantage in using ML engine for ML specific applications and if yes, which differences between Compute Engine and CLoud ML engine make them more preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Google Cloud ML Engine as a layer of abstraction over Google Compute Engine.  Cloud ML Engine manages the computing resources that your training job needs to run, so you can focus more on your model than on hardware configuration or resource management.

TensorFlow is also a core component of Cloud ML Engine.  If you were planning to use a different ML framework that won't work.

Comment: Cost wise, which is better? Can we not use Compute Engine and just run Cloud ML Tensorflow?

Comment: I would guess that ML Engine is more expensive because it's a managed service.  In theory that means it's easier to use but you should checkout the calculator to confirm - https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/.   You can certainly run Tensorflow on Compute Engine.